# Linux Sort vs Perl String Comparison

Tags: perl, string, sorting

Because I was dealing with very large files, I sorted my base and candidate files before comparing them to see what lines were missing from the other. I did this to avoid keeping the records in memory. The sorting was done by using the Linux command-line tool, sort.

In my Perl script, I would look at whether the string in the line was lt, gt, or eq to the line in the other file, advancing the pointers in the file where necessary. However, I hit a problem when I noticed that my string comparison thought the strings in the base file were lt a string in the candidate file which contained special characters.

Is there a surefire way of making sure my Linux sort and Perl string comparisons are using the same type of string comparator?

Comment: Have you looked at `join` or `comm`?  They should work if you only need to see which lines are missing from the other file.

Comment: @Daniel's suggestion is good -- it sounds like you have basically written `comm` in Perl :)  Though interestingly the `comm` manpage doesn't mention locales, so it's possible it would have the same problem as your Perl script.

Answer (score 8):

The `sort` command uses the current locale, as specified by the environment variable `LC_ALL`, to determine the sort order for characters.  Usually the easiest way to fix sorting issues is to manually set this to the `C` locale, which treats each 8-bit byte as a single character and compares by simple numeric value.  In most shells this can be done as a one-off just for a single command by prefixing it like so:

```
LC_ALL=C sort < infile > outfile
```

This will also solve similar problems for some other text-processing programs.  (E.g. I recall problems working with CSV files on a German person's computer -- this was traced back to the fact that Germans use a comma instead of a decimal point.  Putting `LC_ALL=C` in front of the relevant commands fixed that issue too.)

**[EDIT]** Although Perl can be directed to treat some strings as Unicode, by default it still treats input and output as streams of 8-bit bytes, so the above approach should produce an order that is the same as Perl's `sort()` function.  (Thanks to Ven'Tatsu for this nugget.)

Comment: To over simplify: For backwards compatibility the default is still everything that comes in or goes out is a stream of bytes, until Perl is told otherwise. Command line options, pragmas, IO layers, and encoding functions can mark some data as Unicode or apply an encoding specific behavior to some operations or handles.